# Frequent JVM crash possible issue with yourkit?

Tags: java, crash, jvm, yourkit

tomcat server running an application is crashing very frequently . The crash stack trace leads to yourkit agent . Can someone help to find is this truly related to yourkit ?

```
Register to memory mapping:
RAX=0xffffffffffffffff is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000013d87190 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000013e324f0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000000cdea is an unknown value
RSP=0x00002b128ff68450 is pointing into the stack for thread:     0x000000002a36c000
RBP=0x00002b128ff68470 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002a36c000
RSI=0x00002b1264e160e0: <offset 0xfb10e0> in     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00002b1263e65000
RDI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00002b1264e160e0: <offset 0xfb10e0> in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00002b1263e65000
R9 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R10=0x00002b1267d9568f is at entry_point+79 in (nmethod*)0x00002b1267d954d0
R11=0x0000000640825878 is an oop
com.yourkit.probes.WeakKeyMap 
- klass: 'com/yourkit/probes/WeakKeyMap'
R12=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb]

Stack: [0x00002b128feea000,0x00002b128ff6b000],  sp=0x00002b128ff68450,       free space=505k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
 V  [libjvm.so+0x7ba491]  JvmtiTagMap::get_tag(_jobject*)+0x51
 V  [libjvm.so+0x77f1e2]  JvmtiEnv::GetTag(_jobject*, long*)+0x42
V  [libjvm.so+0x736014]  jvmti_GetTag+0x254
 C  [libyjpagent.so+0x1451ee]  ObjectEnumerator::setObjectID(_jobject*, int)+0x3e

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  1246  com.yourkit.runtime.Callback.objectGetID(Ljava/lang/Object;)J (0 bytes) @ 0x00002b1267d9568f [0x00002b1267d95640+0x4f]
J 7480 C2    com.yourkit.probes.ResourceCounter.open(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V   (133 bytes) @ 0x00002b1268d762e0 [0x00002b1268d76280+0x60]
J 23584 C2  com.yourkit.probes.builtin.DatabasesLW$Connection_prepareStatement_Probe.onReturn(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;)V (43 bytes) @ 0x00002b126b38c28c [0x00002b126b38bfa0+0x2ec]
J 8503 C2 oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement; (158 bytes) @ 0x00002b1268f3322c [0x00002b1268f32aa0+0x78c]
```

Comment: Does this happen when you are not using yourkit?  What did they say on the yourkit support forum?  It looks like one particular probe is failing here, what do you see if you turn off all probes (or just this one)?

Comment: i have removed yourkit but still its crashing

Comment: So I don't think yourkit is the cause. Can you update the question an include a crash without yourkit?